# What's the correct syntax for matching a variable in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

What's the correct syntax for matching a variable in bash?

```
#!/bin/bash
# test1.sh

say_hello()
{
    if [ "$1" = true ]; then
        echo "hello"
    else
        echo "goodbye"
    fi
}

say_hello


$ sh test1.sh true
> goodbye
```

If I remove the function, then it works as I expect it to.

```
#!/bin/bash

# test2.sh
if [ "$1" = true ]; then
    echo "hello"
else
    echo "goodbye"
fi


$ sh test2.sh true
> hello
```

I'm not sure what's wrong with the first script's syntax.

Solved and explained by you all, thank you for teaching me.

Comment: BTW, when you run `sh test2.sh`, you run it with a POSIX sh interpreter, not with bash, ignoring the `#!/bin/bash` shebang. If you want to run something as a bash script, you need to run `bash test2.sh`, or set it as executable, use `./test2.sh`, and let the shebang control.

Comment: ...as a second aside, using file extensions on executable scripts is bad form -- contrary to UNIX convention for command names, as you run `ls`, not `ls.elf`; and leads to confusion when a script is rewritten in a different language (do you modify every single program that can call it? Have the name and the implementation language differ? etc).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Basically I second that. I remember a long going discussion with co-workers about that. Is there a convention in, let's say, POSIX about that?

Comment: That's a nice point you make, but should it be called `test` then I might forget that it is a script. ^^

Comment: @rayanamukami, you shouldn't name your own commands `test` anyhow, since that's a name also used by an OS-provided command. As for forgetting that it's a script... why should anyone have to remember what language each command they run is written in? If you want to know what file type something is, that's what `file` is for.

Comment: Thanks, `file` seems very useful. Until now I have found it useful for determining which program to open it with, but one shouldn't indeed have to remember what language it is written in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function in bash has its own list of positional parameters - the arguments, you passed to the function.

As in other programming languages, you need to pass the parameter from the main script to the function:

```
say_hello()
{
    if [ "$1" = "true" ]; then
        echo "hello"
    else
        echo "goodbye"
    fi
}

say_hello "$1"
```

Btw, `"true"` is just a *string* in this context, not a *boolean value* like in other programming languages. I would quote it, simply to express that.

---

Another thing, you are using `#!/bin/bash` in the shebang line, but you call the script using `sh script.sh`. While `/bin/sh` is a link to `/bin/bash` in some systems, it does not necessarily need to be. Even then, bash will recognize that is has started as `/bin/sh` and will run in compatibility mode. If you want to call a script with *bash*, use `bash script.sh`.

Comment: `say_hello "$1"`, to avoid side effects (what if it's `'*'`, or something with a space?)

Comment: Sorry, just copied that. Sure!

Comment: Functions hardly run in a subshell, although the argument list is certainly local.

Comment: I'm embarrassed for missing that. Well, they _can_, if defined with `say_hello() ( ... )` rather than `say_hello() { ... }`, but certainly not the case here.

Comment: Removed that, I really thought that I'm certain about that. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, even *if* `/bin/sh` is a link to `bash`, that still doesn't make them equivalent; when called `sh`, bash enters compatibility mode.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I was not 100% certain if this is configurable, that's why I opted that out.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `ln -s /bin/bash sh; ./sh -c '[[ "1" && "1" ]] && echo "bash"'` works for me. .... /* I will be afk for a while */

Comment: @hek2mgl, it's not *complete* POSIX compatibility, but it's still less capable than full bash is. Allows some bashisms, but not all of them. Same behavior as `set -o posix` has.

Answer (score 1):

`$1` is the first input argument to the script, but inside the scope of a function it is the first argument to that function. So, this would work:

```
#!/bin/bash
# test1.sh

say_hello()
{
    if [ "$1" = true ]; then
        echo "hello"
    else
        echo "goodbye"
    fi
}

say_hello "$1"


$ sh test1.sh true
> goodbye
```

Note that here we are passing the `$1` argument along to the function.

Comment: `say_hello "$1"`, to avoid side effects if there's a literal wildcard, a string with whitespace, etc